# Javascript - SendKeystrokes

Tags: javascript

Is there a way I can send a key stroke to the browser from JavaScript? For example: I would like to trigger the key F11 through JavaScript so that my browser goes to theater mode.

Comment: Related question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Nivas, I'm just posting the code snippet which i tried and was successful in achieving the fullscreen through javascript.

```
function fullscreen() {
    params = 'width=' + screen.availWidth;
    params += ', height=' + screen.availHeight;
    params += ', fullscreen=yes';
    params += ', status=no,titlebar=no,location=0,top=0, left=0';
    window.open(window.location, "test", params);
}
```

I posted the code so that it would be a ready-made solution for one who is searching for fullscreen through javascript.

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot send keystrokes to the browser with just pure javascript.
And the world is safe that way. Otherwise, the first thing i will do is if browser==firefox SendKeys(Alt + (T + I + S + W) and copy all the stored passwords

But if your intention is to have the browser in full screen mode (and you gave a legitimate reason to do so, like oprning a window with photos for slideshow for instance) you can

- Open a pop up without the toolbars, address bar, status bar etc
  or
- Use flash/silverlight to open a full screen view (like in YouTube)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Opening a window without toolbar is better. I tried to create the script which works.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  I presume "theater mode" means making the browser window fullscreen.  Put simply, you cannot do this.  It would be the source of enormous security flaws and usability problems if a website owner could do things like that to the browser window.

Would you like your browser to be continually jumping into fullscreen mode at the whim of the creator of a website?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My scenario is, when the user clicks the fullscreen button in my website, it should move to fullscreen mode.